# google map current location preview

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

hello there i have following code from google geoloction api..
this api is fetching an image of the current location of mine..
what i need to do is display these coordinates in google map(not in an image)

code is as follow:

```
function geoFindMe() {
    var output = document.getElementById("out");

    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

        output.appendChild(img);
    };

    function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
    };

    output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

your help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0q98isRmWp9CNn3p1Vp?p=preview) to help you out! Just fill up the needed data on the iframe with yours and it will work. But instead of setting it to the img src you need to append it to the html.